# Finding the Primary Key and Normalising a Relation with Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I am studying for my databases exam and I've realized my professor did not teach a section of the normalization lecture notes, but glossed over them so I've been self studying and there is this example without solutions in the notes and I was wondering if I have been doing it right:

Given Relation `R = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}`

And functional dependencies:

```
A,B -> C
A -> D,E
B -> F
F -> G,H
D -> I,J
```

1. Determine the primary key
2. Decompose R so it is in 2NF then show it in 3NF.

So, I got the primary key to be `(A, B, D, F)`

And then I tried to convert it to 2NF and I got relations:

```
(ABC), (DIJ), (ADE), (BF), (FGH)
```

And I honestly have no idea if this is right or how to then put it in 3NF... or if I've just skipped 2NF and already put it in 3NF. Any help?

Comment: ABDF determines all the other attributes, so it's a superkey. But ABD also determines all the attributes. That means that ABDF isn't a candidate key. (It's not a *minimal* superkey.)

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? What determines G and H since I thought F did?

Comment: Since B->F, B determines everything that F determines. The closure of B must include the closure of F.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for explaining.

So does that mean it will only work like that? Since A -> D, E then A can't determine everything D determines? Meaning D is a candidate key?

Comment: A->DE means that A->D and A->E ([rule of decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms#Decomposition)). Since A->D, the closure of A must include the closure of D. I have no idea why you might think that D is a candidate key.

Comment: I'm so confused, so D isn't a candidate key? I thought ABD determined all the attributes, isn't that what a candidate key is.

Sorry, I was taught this very poorly, and I am trying to self-study it now and I am finding it very confusing.

Also, I don't get what a closure is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76814/discussion-between-display-and-mike-sherrill-cat-recall).

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we don't know exactly what algorithm you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you have skipped the NF2 and normalised the relation straight into the 3NF :)

The primary key for the original relation should be (**A,B**) as by inference rules (transitivity, such as A->D,E and D->I,J therefore A->I,J) it determines all other attributes. From this point onwards we have that:

- FD1: A,B -> C
- FD2: A -> D,E (Partial)
- FD3: B -> F (Partial)
- FD4: F -> G,H
- FD5: D -> I,J

#### **2NF** (No partial dependencies allowed)

Now we can decompose the relation in three relations moving partial FDs to separate relations but preserving other FDs which might depend on those partial FDs, such as FD2 and FD5. This would give us the following results:

- R1(**A**,D,E,I,J) -- FD2, FD5 (transitive)
- R2(**B**,F,G,H) -- FD3 FD4 (transitive)
- R3(**A,B**,C) -- FD1

Next, to achieve **3NF**, transitive dependencies would have to be removed into separate relations in the same manner as NF2. Which, in turn, would result in the set of relations which you have already derived.

Good luck with your exams!

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! Since posting the question I've grown a bit more confident with normalising, and finding Primary Keys, but this is a fantastic answer. :)

Comment: @Display & Konaras: Normalization does not require going through normal forms in order, and the set of decompositions in a lower normal form can even not include any that lead to the best designs of a higher normal form. (Although here the assignment is specifically to find 2NF.)